# How do I zip a .app file using terminal?

Tags: terminal, applications, zip

I'm having trouble zipping a `.app` file. If I zip without `-r` (recursive) it is really shallow, if I zip with `-r` it's really dense. The zip doesn't unzip correctly regardless.

Answer (score 5):

From the man page for `ditto`:

```
ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent src_directory archive.zip
```

Comment: This still isn't preserving codesigning, although it does answer the question. :/

Comment: @ThomasReggi, I just tried it with code signing and it worked for me.  Is there something unusual about your app like a non-Mach-o executable?

Comment: Not sure what that is I just signed and got `signed bundle with Mach-O thin`. I'm signing with this command `codesign --verbose --deep --force --sign "Company, LLC." Atom.app` I'm lost and can use any help, when I verify I get `nested code is modified or invalid`

Comment: I figured it out with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266954/codesign-deep-on-mavericks-xcode-5-0-5a1412